# Running game without a physical CD drive

Tags: windows-8.1, compact-disc, copy-protection

My copy of Age of Empires II (Microsoft, 1999) is perfectly legal, bought about 15 years ago. Recently I installed the game on my new laptop running Windows 8.1. The game still works great out-of-the-box!

Like many newer models, my laptop does not have a built-in DVD-ROM. You need to plug in an external USB DVD player. However, the DVD-ROM is bulky and a hassle to use, so mostly sits in a drawer. In normal operation, Windows Explorer just shows the C-drive.

When I try and run AoE2 without the DVD-ROM installed and the game CD in the drive, I get the error:

`Please insert the correct CD-ROM, select OK and restart application`

Is there a way to trick AoE2 into thinking the CD is available? Maybe there is a registry change specific to this game or the CD can be converted to some other format like an ISO?

Note: I'd prefer not to download a different version of this game if at all possible!

Comment: an ISO would be the solution. In this situation though, I'd sorely be tempted to get the newer HD version off of steam

Comment: Well, its nice to have the physical CD copy and I really like the older-style graphics and gameplay. The new version has updated, and undoubtedly more CPU-intensive, graphics. How do I go about converting the CD into an ISO? Is it easy to mount?

Comment: windows 8 mounts them directly. Not sure what I'd use to image nowadays.

Comment: After a bit of searching, I found this article which describes it (http://www.howtogeek.com/228886/how-to-create-iso-files-from-discs-on-windows-mac-and-linux/). Will give InfraRecorder a trial tonight and report back. And you're right, seems Windows 8.1 can mount ISOs natively! Cool.

Comment: @AlainD Alcohol 120% was what I used back in the day for games like this when I didn't want to swap discs out of a binder all the time.  Looks similar to what you found and I think would also have to be a trial version. http://www.alcohol-soft.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a Non-CD-Exe. Since you have the game it is totaly legal to use such a thing. Those are mostly used for pirating games so I'm not gonna post any link here. Google should give you an answer. An ISO would be another solution but it takes way more time and you have to bypass the DRM either way.

Comment: I tried looking for a no-CD version, but wasn't able to find any. You're probably right that its legal, but I feel a little worried about it. Firstly, the binary has been modified by a 3rd party that may not be 100% trustworthy and secondly the no-CD versions are used for piracy and I want to stay totally legal. I'll persevere with creating and mounting an ISO...

Comment: Then you should try out something like CloneDVD. Not sure if there are better options. It's the only one that comes to my mind. Should be pretty easy to use. To Mount the ISO i suggest using Daemon Tools Light or Virtual CloneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

We use [MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) to create ISO's and mount them and have been doing so for over a decade.  We rarely have problems with it working even when used over a network; that is loading an ISO from a network location.

All of our install discs are ISO's on a network server so we do not have to dig up disc's, ever.  It works so well that the first thing we do when purchasing software is we make it an ISO and store the keys in a separate file where the ISOs are stored then we keep all the COAs in a box in storage for legality reasons.

Installing from an ISO is much faster than a CD, especially if the ISO is stored on a local SSD, and you can have multiple ISO's mounted by using multiple virtual drives so discs that need inserted to use a program you can just leave mounted.

This has worked over the years through multiple operating systems and upgrades over many different computers using the same software and the same ISO's.  It has proved to be a robust solution for us.